# query is taking long time

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, mysql-slow-query-log

```
SELECT  a.sectionid as sectionid, views.timestamp as timestamp,
        views.time_on_page as time_on_page, views.video as video,
        views.access as access, masterid
    FROM (
        SELECT  m.timestamp as timestamp, m.time_on_page as time_on_page,
                AES_DECRYPT(m.IP_Blob, UNHEX(SHA2('Jove Is Cool',512))) as ip_bin,
                m.page as page, m.language as language, m.access as access,
                m.referrer as referrer, m.searchterms as searchterms,
                m.user_id as user_id,
                case when m.page regexp '/pdf(-materials)?/'
                     then replace(replace(replace(RIGHT(m.page, 5), '/', ''), 'd', ''), 'f', '')
                     else m.video end as video,
                m.id as masterid
            FROM  masterstats_innodb as m
            join  stats_to_institution as sti  ON m.id = sti.statid
            JOIN  institutions as ins  ON sti.institutionid = ins.institutionid
            WHERE  m.timestamp BETWEEN '2019-12-30' AND '2020-12-29'
              and  ( ins.institutionid = '2'
                  or ins.parentinstitutionid = '2' ) 
        ) as views
    LEFT JOIN  articles as a  ON views.video = a.productid
       `enter code here`
    order by masterid
```

masterstats_innodb -- 115759655
stats_to_institution -- 45317238
institutions --45038

All possible indexes have been created and partition also created for masterstats_innodb  table.

Comment: How many rows in masterstats_innodb would be between those two dates? I imagine that's going to be a large amount? How many would match the `institutionid` or `parentinstitutionid` filters? And when you combine all the filters, how many would you expect there to be? What have you partitioned the table by?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Answer (score 1):

`OR` does not optimize well; switching to `UNION` is a common fix.  But it is unclear whether that will help.  Which is more selective?  `m.timestamp` or `(ins.institutionid = '2' or  ins.parentinstitutionid = '2')`?

For optimal indexes on `stats_to_institution`:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

`enter code here` does not make sense where it is; please fill in with an example.

Tentative INDEXes:

```
a:  (productid, sectionid)
ins:  (parentinstitutionid, institutionid)
m:  (timestamp)
sti:  (statid, institutionid)
sti:  (institutionid, statid)
```